# LIBGDX fadeout, hide and remove action not triggered

Tags: libgdx

I try to execute an sequence of actions, but fadeout and following are not working for me. I can see the actor moving to the desired point, but after that it just stays there.

My code. personActor is an Actor of a list in my mainactor:

```
    SequenceAction sequence = new SequenceAction();
    sequence.addAction(Actions.moveTo(0, 300));
    sequence.addAction(Actions.moveTo(1000, 300,3f));
    sequence.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(0.5f));
    sequence.addAction(Actions.hide());
    sequence.addAction(Actions.removeActor());

    personActor.addAction(sequence);
```

The main actor loops through the list of childactors:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    for(PersonActor personActor : personenActors){
        personActor.draw(batch,parentAlpha);
    }
}
```

Do someone see, whats wrong here ?

Comment: Probably you forgot to call `stage.act(delta);`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.
My Person actor has Sprites drawn in the draw() method of the Actor.

I just had to set the color of the Textures in draw() to the Actors color:

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    texture.setColor(getColor)
```